# First Transition not smooth jQuery fade in/out

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery codes that cycles through a series of divs. I have it so the current div fades out and the next div then fades in in its place. The problem is on the first transition, the visible div doesn't fade out, it just disappears. After that first transition, the rest of the transitions are smooth with proper fade in/out motion. The following is an example of the divs:

```
<div id="testimonials">
    <div class="testimony current">
        <p>Text1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="testimony">
        <p>Text2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following is the jQuery for the transitions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cycle = window.setInterval(next, 6000);

    function next() {
        $('#testimonials .current').removeClass('current').fadeOut(500).next().add('#testimonials div:first').last().fadeIn(2000).addClass('current');
    }
});
```

You can see the awkward first transition at: http://jrubins.webfactional.com/tamid/vision.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of calling `fadeOut()` and `removeClass()` methods, try this:

```
function next() {
   $('#testimonials .current').fadeOut(500, function(){
       $(this).removeClass('current')
   }).next()...
}
```

Comment: Yeah if you check the site, you'll see the code is updated with your suggestion but the same effect happens

Comment: @jrubins Yes, obviously as element's display property is set to none that effect happens. Try using `fadeOut` callback function.

Comment: I don't understand why it would happen for just the first transition...?

Comment: @jrubins It should be related to the queue of animations.